# AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt

Tags: akka, azure-cosmosdb

I'm getting below warning if I uncomment cosmosAsyncClient method in LocalCosmosDBConfig.java. Getting similar warning if I uncomment cosmosConfig method in the same file. Application is developed using java, akka framework and azure cosmos DB. Application eventually throws the below error after the warning and doesn't even start.

**CosmosDBConfig.java**

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnProperty("condition")
public abstract class CosmosDBConfig extends AbstractCosmosConfiguration {

    protected final CosmosProperties cosmosProperties;

    protected CosmosDBConfig(CosmosProperties cosmosProperties) {
        this.cosmosProperties = cosmosProperties;
    }

    @Override
    public CosmosConfig cosmosConfig() {
        return CosmosConfig.builder()
            .enableQueryMetrics(cosmosProperties.isQueryMetricsEnabled())
            .responseDiagnosticsProcessor(
                responseDiagnostics -> log.info("{} Response Diagnostics {}",
                    getClassName(), responseDiagnostics
                ))
            .build();
    }

    protected CosmosClientBuilder cosmosClientBuilder() {
        CosmosClientBuilder builder = createCosmosClientBuilder();
        setCosmosCredentials(builder);
        return builder;
    }

    @Override
    public CosmosAsyncClient cosmosAsyncClient(CosmosClientBuilder cosmosClientBuilder) {
        return CosmosFactory.createCosmosAsyncClient(cosmosClientBuilder);
    }

    protected void setCosmosCredentials(CosmosClientBuilder builder) {
        if (StringUtils.hasText(getKey())) {
            log.info("Connecting to Cosmos DB using Azure Key Credentials");
            builder.credential(new AzureKeyCredential(getKey()));
        } else {
            log.info("Connecting to Cosmos DB using Azure Token Credentials");
            builder.credential(new DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder().build());
        }
    }

    protected String getClassName() {
        return this.getClass().getSimpleName().replaceAll("\\$.*", "");
    }

    // Children classes will need to implement creation of cosmosClientBuilder with required properties needed for its unique connection
    abstract CosmosClientBuilder createCosmosClientBuilder();

    // Children classes will need to implement how to retrieve its unique connection's key
    abstract String getKey();
}
```

**LocalCosmosDBConfig.java**

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnProperty("condition")
@EnableReactiveCosmosRepositories(basePackages = "com.example.repository",
    reactiveCosmosTemplateRef = "localDatabaseTemplate")
public class LocalCosmosDBConfig extends CosmosDBConfig {

    private static final String LOCAL_COSMOS_CLIENT_BUILDER = "localCosmosClientBuilder";
    private static final String LOCAL_COSMOS_ASYNC_CLIENT = "localCosmosAsyncClient";
    private static final String LOCAL_COSMOS_CONFIG = "localCosmosConfig";

    @Value("${azure.cosmos.regions}")
    private List<String> regions;

    @Value("${azure.cosmos.endpoint-discovery-enabled}")
    private boolean endpointDiscoveryEnabled;

    public LocalCosmosDBConfig(CosmosProperties cosmosProperties) {
        super(cosmosProperties);
    }

    @Override
    protected CosmosClientBuilder createCosmosClientBuilder() {
        log.info("Building {} Cosmos DB Connection for: {}", getClassName(),
            cosmosProperties.getLocalUri()
        );

        return new CosmosClientBuilder().endpoint(cosmosProperties.getLocalUri())
            .gatewayMode(new GatewayConnectionConfig())
            .preferredRegions(regions)
            .endpointDiscoveryEnabled(endpointDiscoveryEnabled);
    }

    @Override
    protected String getKey() {
        return cosmosProperties.getLocalKey();
    }

    @Override
    @Primary
    @Bean(LOCAL_COSMOS_CLIENT_BUILDER)
    public CosmosClientBuilder cosmosClientBuilder() {
        return super.cosmosClientBuilder();
    }

//  @Override
//  @Primary
//  @Bean(LOCAL_COSMOS_ASYNC_CLIENT)
//  public CosmosAsyncClient cosmosAsyncClient(
//      @Qualifier(LOCAL_COSMOS_CLIENT_BUILDER) CosmosClientBuilder cosmosClientBuilder) {
//      log.info("Building {} Cosmos Async Client for: {}", getClassName(), cosmosProperties.getLocalUri());
//      return super.cosmosAsyncClient(cosmosClientBuilder);
//  }

//  @Override
//  @Primary
//  @Bean(LOCAL_COSMOS_CONFIG)
//  public CosmosConfig cosmosConfig() {
//      return super.cosmosConfig();
//  }

    @Bean
    public ReactiveCosmosTemplate localDatabaseTemplate(
//      @Qualifier(LOCAL_COSMOS_ASYNC_CLIENT) CosmosAsyncClient cosmosAsyncClient,
//      @Qualifier(LOCAL_COSMOS_CONFIG) CosmosConfig cosmosConfig,
        CosmosAsyncClient cosmosAsyncClient,
        CosmosConfig cosmosConfig,
        MappingCosmosConverter mappingCosmosConverter) {
        return new ReactiveCosmosTemplate(cosmosAsyncClient, cosmosProperties.getLocalDatabase(), cosmosConfig,
            mappingCosmosConverter
        );
    }

    @Override
    protected String getDatabaseName() {
        return cosmosProperties.getLocalDatabase();
    }

    @Bean
    public CosmosAsyncContainer buildCloudBufferAsyncContainer(
//      @Qualifier(LOCAL_COSMOS_ASYNC_CLIENT) CosmosAsyncClient cosmosAsyncClient
        CosmosAsyncClient cosmosAsyncClient
    ) {
        CosmosAsyncDatabase database = cosmosAsyncClient.getDatabase(this.getDatabaseName());
        return database.getContainer(VehicleCloudEventsContainerName);
    }
}
```

[WARN] - [org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext] - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'cosmosAsyncClient' defined in class path resource [com/example/dispatcher/configuration/LocalCosmosDBConfig.class]: No matching factory method found on class [com.example.dispatcher.configuration.LocalCosmosDBConfig]: factory bean 'localCosmosDBConfig'; factory method 'cosmosAsyncClient()'. Check that a method with the specified name exists and that it is non-static.

[ERROR] - [akka.actor.SupervisorStrategy] - Error creating bean with name 'defaultValidator': Singleton bean creation not allowed while singletons of this factory are in destruction (Do not request a bean from a BeanFactory in a destroy method implementation!)
akka.actor.ActorInitializationException: akka://dispatcher/user/outboundStreamActor-1: exception during creation, root cause message: [Error creating bean with name 'defaultValidator': Singleton bean creation not allowed while singletons of this factory are in destruction (Do not request a bean from a BeanFactory in a destroy method implementation!)]